# left sidebar block double up (want to remove duplicate block)

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I am having a problem where the "Advanced Search Form" displayed on the left sidebar on my home page is duplicated. (http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/).

I previously wanted my home page to be identical to my "product list view" page http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/products.html, I was given a solution where I was told to insert the below code into the content area of my home page CMS area.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list"
alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I did so successfully, but now have a duplicate advanced search form showing on the left sidebar somehow.

**Summary:**

Duplicate block displaying here - http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/

What the page should be looking like - http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/products.html

Comment: is that the only thing in the content section?  Is there anything in the design update tab?

Comment: Yes, the only code I have in the content area is:

<div>
<p><img title="nav bar - chemicals" src="http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/media/Navigation/bar_-_chemicals.jpg" alt="nav bar - chemicals" /></p>
</div>
<div>
<p>{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</p>
</div>

There are no xml updates or anything that I can see that is duplicating this area...bit strange O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation precedes your current attempt...

Go to System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages and set the **Default Web URL** value to the system URL for that category, which is `catalog/category/view/id/3` for your data set (ref http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/catalog/category/view/id/3 ).

HTH

Comment: Ok thanks, answer was using "catalog/category/view/id/3" as the Default Web URL. Found at "system" > "web" > "Default Web URL" then insert "catalog/category/view/id/3". Home page now displays my main products areas as default. Cheers

Comment: Great! If this truly solves the issue, please mark it as correct for others' benefit :-)

Comment: lol I can't mark until I have 15 reputation. One day :). Thanks